# Checking if the file is "in use" by another process

Tags: .net, vb.net, getfiles

I display the files in a directory with `Directory.GetFiles()` and then,

```
Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(file)
```

But I have an error that says:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Do you know how to check if a file is already used by a process?

I'm looking for a one-line solution.

Comment: Use a try-catch.

Comment: @Cal-cium - not a dupe; the proposed duplicate is for a case where the user _wants_ it to throw an error, and it wasn't. It _is_ relevant, however.

Comment: it works with try catch thanks,